# Intellij hangs on generating a large number of graphs

Tags: r, intellij-14

I'm running a Java code on intellij which calls an R script which is supposed to generate abt 2000 graphs. But when I run the code it generates abt 200 and just hangs. It doesn't do anything.

I initially thought it had something to do with the memory allocated to for the application. So i increased the memory allocated using the following link.http://sohu.io/questions/870094/intellij-increase-scalatest-heap-space
But it still doesn't make any difference.

I also tried running the same code from the command line. But it generates the same number of graphs and hangs again.

What could be the issue??

Comment: When you say you tried running the same code from the command line, do you mean you ran the R code? If that's the case and the R code is hanging, it sounds like your problem is with R, not IntelliJ.

Comment: Can you post your R code and data?

Comment: @Alex i ran the java code from the command line. When i run just the R script it works fine.

Comment: @user4655509: Please include some code detailing what R is doing and how Java is calling it.

Comment: The java code for calling R.                                                                        try {
            System.out.println("Exec: '" + rScriptExe + " " + rFile + " " + params + "'");

            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(rScriptExe + " " + rFile + " " + params);

            proc.waitFor();
            int retval = proc.exitValue();
            System.out.println("Exitval: " + retval);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: The R runs a couple of queries and generates a set of graphs using the queries generated.

Comment: I just kept the R and the Java code separate. That was the best way to go about it I figured!